# How to pivot table in r with multiple (or duplicate) text data?

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table

This is a toy example created based on the data of over 30 mil rows.

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), item = c("Job", "DOB", "organization", "info", "Job", 
"DOB", "organization", "info", "Job", "DOB", "organization", 
"info"), value = c("Assistant", "27395", "ABC", "Inspire others", 
"Project manager", "27395", "CDE", "Inspire others", "Project manager", 
"27395", "CDE", "Inspire others")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

I want to create the table with one row per `id`, but I'm running into an issue with it.

```
table %>% pivot_wider(names_from = item, values_from = value)
```

The code above gives me the following result:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 5
     id Job       DOB       organization info     
  <int> <list>    <list>    <list>       <list>   
1     1 <chr [3]> <chr [3]> <chr [3]>    <chr [3]>
```

So, I tried to combine them as a text with `values_fn = list(value = paste)`, but I get the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "val", value = c("Assistant", "Project manager", : replacement has 12 rows, data has 4
```

What's the best way to tackle such problems where the duplicate entries may be a mixture of character and numeric?

The output I want is the following:

```
id  Job                         DOB     organization info
1   Assistant, Project manager  27395   ABC, CDE    Inspire others
```

the Job has multiple values so, it should be separated by a comma (,), and DOB is the same value so it should remain the same. Similarly, comma separated for organization and single item for info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need a sequence column to make the rows unique and then use `pivot_wider`. In the wide format, then we do `summarise_at` to `paste` the elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(rn = rowid(item)) %>%  
    pivot_wider(names_from = item, values_from = value) %>%
    select(-rn) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ str_c(unique(.), collapse = ", "))
# A tibble: 1 x 5
#     id Job                        DOB   organization info          
#  <int> <chr>                      <chr> <chr>        <chr>         
#1     1 Assistant, Project manager 27395 ABC, CDE     Inspire others
```

---

Or another option is to make use of `values_fn` from `pivot_wider`

```
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = item, values_from = value, 
        values_fn = list(value =  ~ toString(unique(.))))
# A tibble: 1 x 5
#     id Job                        DOB   organization info          
#  <int> <chr>                      <chr> <chr>        <chr>         
#1     1 Assistant, Project manager 27395 ABC, CDE     Inspire others
```

Comment: that was the quickest response I've ever seen. But this still shows 3 different rows for the same ID. I only want a single row by combining the results, or any suggestions are welcome. But the end result should be a single row.

Comment: @user1828605 it can be either a `list` or a string.  which one do you want

Comment: This is brilliant!! I can make do with it, but is there a simple solution to do what I shown in the output? with only a single value if multiple values exist?